# XCode 4.2.1 iOS 5 Expected function body after function declarator

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5

2.1

I am getting error during compilation

> Expected function body after function declarator.

My code is quite simple and I found that this problem 
occur in former XCode versions but I can't find solution
for version 4.2.1. Does somebody have same problem ?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface CalculatorBrain : NSObject

_ (void)pushOperand:(double)operand;

_ ( double)performOperation:(NSString *) operation;

@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a minus "-" character instead of underscore "_".

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface CalculatorBrain : NSObject

- (void)pushOperand:(double)operand;

- (double)performOperation:(NSString *)operation;

@end
```